# Rendering Json response

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the JSON response obtained using `fetch` as a table, however I am unable to store the response data as a state attribute.

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/user/" + this.state.external_id + "/details"
fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseText) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(responseText));
        this.setState({
            data: JSON.stringify(responseText)
        })
    })
    .then(console.log(this.state))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("No such User")
    });
}
...
```

What I'm trying to do is get the JSON response and save it in a `state` variable. Would be really helpful if I could get some help in displaying the response data as a table.

Comment: Could you add it to the `state` variable?

Comment: `.then(response => response.json())` this line turns the response json (string) into a JS object (or array, depending on the response). You can store this as a state attribute. The line following this, you've named this object "responseText" which is misleading, as it's actually an object/array

Comment: you can just use `this.setState({data: responseText})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> The **JSON.stringify()** method converts a JavaScript object or value
>   to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function
>   is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if
>   a replacer array is specified.

Data from `Object` type becomes `String`.

`this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(responseText) })`

Instead above, `setState` like:

`this.setState({ data: responseText })`

**JSFiddle** example:

```js
class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
     return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    
  return (
     <div>
       <h1>Posts JSON:</h1>
       <pre>
         {JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)}
       </pre>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Data />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.9/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.9/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Marko Savics answer, do the following in your `render()` method to display it as a table:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Results Table</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.state.data.map(item => (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.userId}</tr>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{item.title}</td>
                <td>{item.body}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          }
        </tbody> 
      </table>
   </div>
);
```

The key thing is to remove `JSON.stringify(responseText)` when you call `setState`, and just call it like so:

```
setState({ data: responseText });
```